Why is there a colour difference between stars and hot objects since they are both black-body radiators?
I have a question about the color of a black-body radiator that has been baffling me for a few years now, and I haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer. So, we know that a star's color depends on its temperature, as determined by Planck's law. For example, a cool M-type dwarf (temperature of 2-4 KK) will appear red. A G or F-type star with a temp of 5-7 KK will appear yellow or white. An O-type star with a temp of 30 KK will appear blue. However, it looks like the same relationship doesn't hold true for a hot object, say a metal. We know a heated object starts glowing red when the temperature is beyond the Draper point at 525°C. It then turns to bright orange at around 900°C, then bright yellow at 1200°C, and finally white at temps above 1400°C. So, as we can see, there is a huge difference between the color-temperature relation of stars and everyday objects, even though their thermal radiation is governed by the same physical laws. Why is that?

Many duplicates. BtW M dwarfs have a spectrum that is very unlike a blackbody.

See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/354755/ https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/129731/

Possible duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/304299/ https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/339942/
